# iOS8 Share Extension with Dropbox Photo Integration

Tags: image, ios8, dropbox, ios-app-extension, ios8-share-extension

I've been working on a share extension and am now trying to have it activate within dropbox when sharing images. I notice Mail, FB, and Twitter are in the list, however mine is not. My `NSExtensionActivationRule` accepts `NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount`, `NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount`, `NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount`, `NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMaxCount`, `NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount`. Any ideas?

*Note: the extension does work on the camera picker.*

Comment: Have you added the extension with your app?. After you add the extension you need to create new provisional for main app and the extension, those provisional should enable group app and use same group identifier for both provisional.